# Vue: How to place the radio button at the center of the label

Tags: css, sticky

## Place radio Button at Label's Center

How to place the radio button at a vertical-center? Presently I used `top: 50 %`, But it is not aligning to center. I'm not hard-coding the height of the right `div`. I wish to use a function to assign the top-value, however; the height of the right div is dynamic.

###### *Is there any way I can get the height?*

[image]

```
                <b-tabs>
                    <b-tab>
                        <b-form-radio-group>
                            <b-form-radio>
                                <div>Lorem .....</div>
                            </b-form-radio>
                        </b-form-radio-group>
                    </b-tab>
                </b-tabs>
                .custom-control-label {
                  &:before {
                    background: $white;
                    border: 2px solid #b7b9bc;
                    border-radius: 100%;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    top: 50%;
                   }
                   &:after {
                    top: 50%;
                   }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio button had a height of 16px. So gave top propoerty to :after and :before like this which solved the issue.

```
    .custom-control-label {
        &:before {
            background: $white;
            border: 2px solid #b7b9bc;
            border-radius: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: calc((100% - 16px)/2);
        }
        &:after {
            top: calc((100% - 16px)/2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
top: 50%;
transform:translateY(-50%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
top: 50%;
transform:translateY(-100%)
```

You aligning center the element on the top `50%` starting point, so you need to translate it `-100%` of its own height to center it.

Comment: Its not getting center aligned after this too, i gave this property to before and after !